# Induction over Rham piecewise linear function

Tags: analysis, induction, fractals

The following exercise is inspired in Daubechies - Lagarias:  **Two-Scale Difference Equations, Existence and Global Regularity of Solutions.**

Define the following functions:

$$f_0(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1+x &   \text{if}  & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
             \\ 1-x &  \text{if} & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
             \\ 0 &  \text{if}  & \vert x \vert \geq 1
             \end{array}
   \right. $$

Now we construct $f_1$ as follows: $f_1$ is linear in the restrictions to an interval of the form $[m/3,(m+1)/3]$ for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. The nodes of $f_1$ are given by $f_1(m)=f_0(m)$, $f_1(m+1/3)=f_0(m+2/3)$, $f_1(m+2/3) = f_0(m+1/3)$, for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then, do a linear interpolation between this nodes. The same procedure is repeated to obtain $f_{j+1}$ from $f_j$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. The resulting $f_j$ are piecewise linear, with linear restrictions to the intervals $[m3^{-j},(m+1)3^{-j}]$, for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now we want to check that:

$$f_{n+1} = Vf_n.$$

Where:

$$Vf(x) = f(3x)+\frac{1}{3}[f(3x+1)+f(3x-1)]+\frac{2}{3}[f(3x+2)+f(3x-2)]$$

The authors said that "it can be checked fairly easy...". I'm trying to show by induction, but I don't know how to start. I know that the formula of $V$ is an linear interpolation but I don't understand really well. I will be gratefull for any explanation or an attemp to demonstrate the formula. :(

Comment: If $f_1(m) = f_0(m)$ for all $m \in \Bbb Z$, then you need to define $f_0(m)$ for all $m \in \Bbb Z$. Right now, you've only defined $f_0(x)$ for $x \ge -1$. Also, since $f_0(x) = 0$ for all $x \ge 1$, the same will hold true of $f_1$, and therefore for $f_j$ for all $j$, so this "for all $m \in \Bbb Z$" thing doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think $f_0(x)$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, maybe you missed the $|\cdot|$ in the definition?